# facing error while login with facebook using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth,problem is  that when i am  trying to login with facebook,here showing the error

```
Invalid App ID: None
```

and for that i have place the SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP-ID and SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_SECRET
in my settings.py,and i have also change my hostname also,

here is my settings.py file

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join


sys.path.insert(0, '../..')

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ROOT_PATH = abspath(dirname(__file__))

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
  )

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'test.db'
}
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montevideo'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = '#$5btppqih8=%ae^#&amp;7en#kyi!vh%he9rg=ed#hm6fnw9^=umc'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
 #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
 )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'social.apps.django_app.default',
  'example.app',
)

LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social.backends.amazon.AmazonOAuth2',
'social.backends.angel.AngelOAuth2',
'social.backends.aol.AOLOpenId',
'social.backends.appsfuel.AppsfuelOAuth2',
'social.backends.behance.BehanceOAuth2',
'social.backends.belgiumeid.BelgiumEIDOpenId',
'social.backends.bitbucket.BitbucketOAuth',
'social.backends.box.BoxOAuth2',
'social.backends.coinbase.CoinbaseOAuth2',
'social.backends.dailymotion.DailymotionOAuth2',
'social.backends.disqus.DisqusOAuth2',
'social.backends.douban.DoubanOAuth2',
'social.backends.dropbox.DropboxOAuth',
'social.backends.evernote.EvernoteSandboxOAuth',
'social.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
'social.backends.fedora.FedoraOpenId',
'social.backends.fitbit.FitbitOAuth',
'social.backends.flickr.FlickrOAuth',
'social.backends.foursquare.FoursquareOAuth2',
'social.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'social.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
'social.backends.google.GooglePlusAuth',
'social.backends.instagram.InstagramOAuth2',
'social.backends.jawbone.JawboneOAuth2',
'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth',
'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
'social.backends.live.LiveOAuth2',
'social.backends.livejournal.LiveJournalOpenId',
'social.backends.mailru.MailruOAuth2',
'social.backends.mendeley.MendeleyOAuth',
'social.backends.mixcloud.MixcloudOAuth2',
'social.backends.odnoklassniki.OdnoklassnikiOAuth2',
'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
'social.backends.openstreetmap.OpenStreetMapOAuth',
'social.backends.orkut.OrkutOAuth',
'social.backends.persona.PersonaAuth',
'social.backends.podio.PodioOAuth2',
'social.backends.rdio.RdioOAuth1',
'social.backends.rdio.RdioOAuth2',
'social.backends.readability.ReadabilityOAuth',
'social.backends.reddit.RedditOAuth2',
'social.backends.runkeeper.RunKeeperOAuth2',
'social.backends.skyrock.SkyrockOAuth',
'social.backends.soundcloud.SoundcloudOAuth2',
'social.backends.stackoverflow.StackoverflowOAuth2',
'social.backends.steam.SteamOpenId',
'social.backends.stocktwits.StocktwitsOAuth2',
'social.backends.stripe.StripeOAuth2',
'social.backends.suse.OpenSUSEOpenId',
'social.backends.thisismyjam.ThisIsMyJamOAuth1',
'social.backends.trello.TrelloOAuth',
'social.backends.tripit.TripItOAuth',
'social.backends.tumblr.TumblrOAuth',
'social.backends.twilio.TwilioAuth',
'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
'social.backends.vk.VKOAuth2',
'social.backends.weibo.WeiboOAuth2',
'social.backends.xing.XingOAuth',
'social.backends.yahoo.YahooOAuth',
'social.backends.yahoo.YahooOpenId',
'social.backends.yammer.YammerOAuth2',
'social.backends.yandex.YandexOAuth2',
'social.backends.email.EmailAuth',
'social.backends.username.UsernameAuth',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/done/'
URL_PATH = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social.strategies.django_strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.default.models.DjangoStorage'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
# SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_FORM_URL = '/signup-email'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_FORM_HTML = 'email_signup.html'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_VALIDATION_FUNCTION = 'example.app.mail.send_validation'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_VALIDATION_URL = '/email-sent/'
# SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_FORM_URL = '/signup-username'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_FORM_HTML = 'username_signup.html'

#For Facebool Login using Social Auth
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_ID='***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_SECRET='****************************'


SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'example.app.pipeline.require_email',
'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)

try:
    from example.local_settings import *
    except ImportError:
pass
```

now what i left for facebook login using python social auth?my app id and api key is absolutly right,i have checked it,so whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem occuring because i have wrote

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_ID='***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_SECRET='****************************'
```

in my settings.py

it must be

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='****************************'
```

now it's working...